# Issues with SODA discovery API: Total datasets returned differs from datasets listed in browsing

Tags: socrata, soda

Currently I see that by using the `https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1` API, I faced some issues concerning the total number of datasets returned, with respect to the total number of datasets visualized in the catalog of a given city.

Let's take for  instance Austin, TX: from , I can see in the browser that 3686 Results are listed; however the call (`https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=data.austintexas.gov`)  returns just 2289 datasets metadata records.

It appears that several datasets are missed.

(Similarly behaves Los Angeles: 932 returned by  `https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=data.lacity.org`, while 1428 Results are reported on the catalog )

To try to look into it, I found that another API returning the list of datasets metadata, is `https://data.austintexas.gov/api/views?page=1`, which returned almost all the datasets (3677), just 9 missed. However in this case the metadata structure deeply differs from the one returned by the previous API (less structured and fewer metadata items).

Can someone explain this and which is the **right** API?

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in what are listed on the catalog versus what is available the Discovery API. The Discovery API does not list the following types of data:

- Data Lens pages, which are numerous (e.g., Austin has 188)
- Forms
- External Links
- Measures
- File or Document

This would likely cause counts in the Catalog to be higher than the API. I've not double-checked these types of data to see if they fully explain the difference, but is a known difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the prompt reply. However, I ask You if is there any 'crucial' reason to assume that the canonical API towards Socrata is https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=<domain_URI> instead of https://data.austintexas.gov/api/views?page=1 (in the case of Austin), and thus alwasy prefer the former.

Comment: It'll depend on what you need. Data Lens, forms, external links, etc., do not have consumable, machine-readable data and so they're excluded from the Discovery API. Thus, should be good if you're just wanting to consume data from one or more portals. However, if you need to know those types of data exist, then you'll need the city-specific end-points.